# MonoGame thinks shorter file directories are longer

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xna, monogame

Whenever I try importing an FBX file into the MonoGame Pipeline, it tells me that my FBX has a file path that is too long. While I would normally shorten it, I've found that other resources have longer file names and import just fine.
[Here's the screenshot of what I'm talking about.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KlB7D.png)

Not only this, but other FBX files import just fine in other projects
[like this one.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iy8R6.png)

How do I fix this bug?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently what fixed it was that I had to export as FBX 2014/2015 rather than 2013